# How to rewrite wordpress urls with index.php in them

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to make custom WordPress URLs like this : `http://example.com/index.php?productID=123` and for categories `http://example.com/index.php?categoryID=123` and the reason is we have a website written in some old custom CMS and we want to move it to WordPress and we don't want to lose our indexes in google, The problem here is whenever we include `index.php` in custom URL rewrite it doesn't work and it automatically removes the `index.php`

here are the codes i tried:

```
add_rewrite_rule('index.php?p=(.*)', 'index.php?productId=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('index.php?cat=(.*)', 'index.php?categoryId=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

I also tried [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) , it works fine but the problem is it converts the `?` into `%3F` in URLs which causes 404 error

Comment: i think you have the values mixed up, the regex should be the first argument and the uri pattern you want to match, the second is the uri you want to parse. but the rewrite api is not called unless you are using pretty urls.. you could a hook (maybe init) to parse the url before 404 kicks in and include the file. But it would be better in the long run to use pretty urls

Answer (score 2):

You should use 301 redirects in the `.htaccess` file, as per Google' suggestion. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

An example of a line you'd add to your `.htaccess` would be:
`redirect 301 /index.php?oldProduct=123 /index.php?newProduct=123`

But you really have limitless options. You can see more examples at http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm